# How to consume REST api with Android

Tags: android, rest

I am trying to create a mobile client using android to consume a local REST API
I have created rest server on eclipse and it is running without problems
but i am trying to create my client on android studio and it is running also but when i click on the button nothing is happening.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Button btnChercher;
    private TextView tvJson;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnChercher = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnchercher);
        tvJson = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvJson);
        btnChercher.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                           @Override
                                           public void onClick(View v) {
                                               new JsonTask().execute("http://localhost:8080/membres");
                                           }


                                       }
        );
    }


    public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpURLConnection connection=null;
            BufferedReader reader=null;

            try {
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));

                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line ="";

                while ((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
                    buffer.append(line);
                }

                String finalJson = buffer.toString();

                JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject();
                JSONArray parentArray = parentObject.getJSONArray("");
                JSONObject finalObject = parentArray.getJSONObject(0);

                String nomMembre = finalObject.getString("nomMembre");

                return nomMembre+"\n";





            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if(connection!=null){
                    connection.disconnect();
                }

                if(reader!=null){
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }


            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            tvJson.setText(result);
        }
    }
}`
```

Comment: Look into using [Retrofit](http://square.github.io/retrofit/) it simplifies much of the work of creating a REST client.

Answer (score 1):

Your example shows the URL `"http://localhost:8080/membres"`. Is that intentional? Is your Android application running your web server?

Probably not. `"http://localhost:8080/membres"` works on your computer because `localhost` is referring to your machine itself.

In order to make your Android app access your REST API, you should to do one of the following:

- Replace `localhost` with the IP of your server. This will require your Android app to be on the same network as your server.
- Host your application somewhere else, like Heroku. Replace `localhost:8080` with the publicly accessible URL.

There are other options, but these are the simplest.

Comment: Another option (to avoid be connected to same network) is redirect ports in your router but this requires a fixed ip in order to connect always to the same direction.

Comment: think you brother ggmathur for your explanation

Comment: but when i replace it by my ip adress it runs, but it doesn't display anything when i look in the eclipse console i can see the Hibernate requetes, did I make mistake in JSON code

Comment: I think that the problem i have is that the Json Object returned by the api doesn't have a name   [{"idMembre":1,"nomMembre":"Hassen"}]